# What flight conditions trigger the "altitude, altitude" callout on an A-10?

Tags: gpws, fairchild-a-10, cockpit-alerts

I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHMbkKi-QYo) that shows an A-10 mission in Afghanistan. At 4:31 and 6:08 the callout "Altitude, altitude" is audible.

I would like to know which flight conditions are required to trigger the callout.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Comment: You would need a manual that describes the particular Ground Proximity Warning System parameters for the A-10.  It'll be something on the lines of radar altitude below a threshold value, with a descent rate above a threshold, and terrain closure rate (due to sloping ground) above a threshold.